# Friendliness in French writing

Tags: langage-informel

In French , is there a way to make my writing seem more friendly and less formal?  In English, you can add words like “well…” and “so…” to make it sound like your talking to a friend instead of a stranger or your boss.

“Today I went to school…” - formal, distant, like talking to a stranger
“Well/so, today to school…” - friendly, more intimate

How can I do this in french?

“Aujourd’hui je suis allé à l’école…” - trop formale?

Comment: Welcome ! I think your _Well/so, today to school_… is really not clear, there's no verb. It certainly wouldn't be about the past. A complete sentence or standard syntax doesn't make it formal per se. Maybe the choice of lexicon would but none of the words you chose are formal to begin with imho.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely, there are a few tips, for example you can avoid using "ne" to mean negation, and use specific expressions, an example here:

"*Je ne m'embarrasse pas*" becomes "*Je me prends pas la tête*" or even "*J'me prends pas la tête*".

You could also consider using "*tu*" instead of "*vous*" if you want to be closer to the person reading your text.

Your example in French does not either look too formal or not formal it just looks normal.

You can also adapt your vocabulary, in french language we have different level of politness, le langage soutenu "high" is to avoid here.

If you want additional details I can edit the answer as I cannot comment yet...

Comment: Speaking of pronouns, you can also replace *nous* with *on* (third singular form): *on a mangé* instead of *nous avons mangé*, less verbose and less formal. The usage of *nous* is mostly seen in books or when people are very formally talking (to their boss, an authority, etc.)